# Bootstrap 4 COLLAPSAE // hide other collapsable divs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make 4 pictures, when clicked on, open collapsable div. I got that part, but the problem is that when I click on the second picture the content from the first image are still visible. They would need to hide
I have tried the solutions from here and from all over of internet, but with no success.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pqhz5jLa/

```
   
  <div  class="row">

    <div  class="col" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/71/Black.png" width="100%">
    </div>

    <div class="col" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/71/Black.png" width="100%">
    </div>

   <div class="col" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/71/Black.png" width="100%" >
    </div>
      
      <div class="col" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample4" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/71/Black.png" width="100%" >
    </div>
  </div>     
          <br>        
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample1" >
  <div class="card card-body">
  1
  </div>
</div>       
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample2">
  <div class="card card-body">
    2
  </div>
</div>
                   
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample3">
  <div class="card card-body">
    3
  </div>
</div>
                   
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample4">
  <div class="card card-body">
    4
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: You may want to look into accordions rather than collapse. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/#accordion-example

Comment: Thank you, but i need a particular design that is not possible with that. I want that the 4 jpgs are in one row and the hidden content appears beneath them.

Comment: You can still use the accordion and separate out the sections. Like this https://jsfiddle.net/kv5chdq6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this problem with using javascript. First of all I would give each collapsible div a own class

```
<div class="collapse collapseExample1" id="collapseExample1" >
  <div class="card card-body">
    1
  </div>
</div>       
<div class="collapse collapseExample2" id="collapseExample2">
  <div class="card card-body">
    2
  </div>
</div>
               
<div class="collapse collapseExample3" id="collapseExample3">
  <div class="card card-body">
    3
  </div>
</div>
               
<div class="collapse collapseExample4" id="collapseExample4">
  <div class="card card-body">
    4
  </div>
</div>
```

and then this js should fix the problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".collapseExample1").on('show.bs.collapse', function(){
            $(".collapseExample2").collapse("hide");
            $(".collapseExample3").collapse("hide");
            $(".collapseExample4").collapse("hide");
        });
        $(".collapseExample2").on('show.bs.collapse', function(){
            $(".collapseExample1").collapse("hide");
            $(".collapseExample3").collapse("hide");
            $(".collapseExample4").collapse("hide");
        });
        $(".collapseExample3").on('show.bs.collapse', function(){
            $(".collapseExample1").collapse("hide");
            $(".collapseExample2").collapse("hide");
            $(".collapseExample4").collapse("hide");
        });
        $(".collapseExample4").on('show.bs.collapse', function(){
            $(".collapseExample1").collapse("hide");
            $(".collapseExample2").collapse("hide");
            $(".collapseExample3").collapse("hide");
        });
    });
```

Comment: On this site ( https://blank.mfest.dev/bootstrap/ ) I've posted you an example that works

Comment: it works. but now i have a problem with responsivness. https://jsfiddle.net/5uzgyfnL/ On mobile then text appears on the bottom of 4 pictures, it should appear at the bottom of the picture witch is clicked on.